# How to compare two files and print the values of both the files which are different

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, solaris, filecompare

There are 2 files. I need to sort them first and then compare the 2 files and then the difference I need to print the value from File 1 and File 2.

file1:

```
pair,bid,ask
AED/MYR,3.918000,3.918000
AED/SGD,3.918000,3.918000
AUD/CAD,3.918000,3.918000
```

file2:

```
pair,bid,ask
AUD/CAD,3.918000,3.918000
AUD/CNY,3.918000,3.918000
AED/MYR,4.918000,4.918000
```

Output should be:

```
pair,inputbid,inputask,outputbid,outtputask
AED/MYR,3.918000,3.918000,4.918000,4.918000
```

The only difference in 2 files is AED/MYR with different bid/ask rates. How can I print difference value from file 1 and file 2.

I tried using below commands:

```
nawk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$4;a[$2]=$5;next} !($4 in a) || !($5 in a) {print $1 FS a[$1] FS a[$2] FS $4 FS $5}' file1 file2
```

Result output as below:

```
pair,bid,ask,bid,ask
AUD/CAD,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000
AUD/CHF,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000
AUD/CNH,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000
AUD/CNY,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000,3.918000
AED/MYR,3.918000,3.918000,4.918000,4.918000
```

We are still not able to get only the difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO users are highly encouraged to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems in their question, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Updated the same. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk` with shown samples.

```
awk -v header="pair,inputbid,inputask,outputbid,outtputask" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]=$0
  next
}
($1 in arr) && arr[$1]!=$0{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^,/,"")
  if(!found){
    print header
    found=1
  }
  print arr[val],$0
}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v header="pair,inputbid,inputask,outputbid,outtputask" '  ##Starting awk program from here and setting this to header value here.
BEGIN{                                                         ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                                                   ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
}
FNR==NR{                                                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  arr[$1]=$0                                                   ##Creating arr with index $1 and keep value as current line.
  next                                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr) && arr[$1]!=$0{                                    ##Checking condition if first field is present in arr and its value NOT equal to $0
  val=$1                                                       ##Creating val which has current line value in it.
  $1=""                                                        ##Nullifying irst field here.
  sub(/^,/,"")                                                 ##Substitute starting , with NULL here.
  if(!found){                                                  ##Checking if found is NULL then do following.
    print header                                               ##Printing header here only once.
    found=1                                                    ##Setting found here.
  }
  print arr[val],$0                                            ##Printing arr with index of val and current line here.
}' Input_file1  Input_file2                                    ##Mentioning Input_files here.
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder. Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated. We are working in SunOS It worked with nawk.

Comment: @Siddy_21111990, your welcome and happy learning cheers :) Yes on Sun OS you need to change it to `nawk`, good job for doing so :)

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` process substitution, then `join` and then choosing with `awk`:

```
# print header
printf "%s\n" "pair,inputbid,inputask,outputbid,outtputask"
# remove first line from both files, then sort them on first field
# then join them on first field and output first 5 fields
join -t, -11 -21 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 <(tail -n +2 file1 | sort -t, -k1) <(tail -n +2 file2 | sort -t, -k1) |
# output only those lines, that columns differ
awk -F, '$2 != $4 || $3 != $5'
```